# Unexpected '{' with IF statement

Tags: php

this is my code to move all the files in a directory to another directory which are 1 hour old or more.

```
<?php
$srcDir = 'code';
$destDir = 'code/old';

if (file_exists($destDir)) {
  if (is_dir($destDir)) {
    if (is_writable($destDir)) {
      if ($handle = opendir($srcDir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if (is_file($srcDir . '/' . $file)) {
              if(date("U",filectime($srcDir . '/' . $file) >= time() - 3600) {
                rename($srcDir . '/' . $file, $destDir . '/' . $file);
                }

          }
        }
        closedir($handle);
      } else {
        echo "$srcDir could not be opened.\n";
      }
    } else {
      echo "$destDir is not writable!\n";
    }
  } else {
    echo "$destDir is not a directory!\n";
  }
} else {
  echo "$destDir does not exist\n";
}
?>
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/tcity/public_html/myDir/movefiles.php on line 11
```

Comment: on your file which line is line number# 11?

Comment: Wow. I have no words.

Comment: Missing parenthesis typically. Go look yourself however.

Comment: `if(date("U",filectime($srcDir . '/' . $file)) >= time() - 3600) {`

Comment: it tells you right in the error where your mistake is. looking at that line, you can easily find the problem.

Comment: Your code might be more readable (and, thus, more supportable) if you invert your conditionals in this case.  Instead of checking for your positive cases and moving deeper in a bracket hierarchy, check for your negative cases in single-deep conditionals.  This is a common refactoring pattern called Replace Nested Conditional With Guard Clauses: http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a closing parenthesis here:

```
if(date("U",filectime($srcDir . '/' . $file) >= time() - 3600) {
                                            ^
```

You also need to learn to use the `&&` operator to combine logical statements.  Although, it seems you want to provide feedback.  Excessive nesting is difficult to read.  If you want to have all those tests individually, how about this:

```
if (!file_exists($destDir))
{
    echo "$destDir does not exist\n";
}
elseif (!is_dir($destDir))
{
    echo "$destDir is not a directory!\n";
}
elseif (!is_writable($destDir))
{
    echo "$destDir is not writable!\n";
}
elseif (...)
{

}
else
{
   while (...) {
   }
}
```

Comment: stupid me.. i had counted the parenthesis but counted them wrong.. i guess i'm sleepy as its 3:30 AM anyways.. thanks but there is a problem. the script is moving all the files even those created a minute before.. where am I making mistake?

Comment: You're subtracting one hour from the time, so it will move all files created up to an hour ago.  A good trick for matching parentheses is to count like this:  start at 0, add one when you see `(`, subtract one when you see `)`.  If you don't end up back at 0, you're missing something (negative = missing `(`, positive = missing `)`).

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that you have missed a closing paranthesis on the `date()` function call, you should also consider formatting your code better, it is just too hard to watch and find an error(you felt it on your skin).
Write a function to do the job for you:

```
function pleaseDontMakeFunOfTheOtherDevelopers($srcDir, $destDir) {
    if (!is_dir($srcDir)) {
        return "$destDir does not exist\n";
    }
    if (is_writable($destDir)) {
        return "$destDir is not writable!\n";
    }

    if (!($handle = opendir($srcDir))) {
        return "$srcDir could not be opened.\n";
    }

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if (is_file($srcDir . '/' . $file) && date("U", filectime($srcDir . '/' . $file)) >= time() - 3600) {
        rename($srcDir . '/' . $file, $destDir . '/' . $file);
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    return true;
}
```

L.E: guess it's clear enough you should rename the function :)

Comment: you could even go one more step like: `if (!is_dir($srcDir)) return "$destDir does not exist\n";`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parentheses.

```
if(date("U",filectime($srcDir . '/' . $file) >= time() - 3600) {
```

becomes

```
if(date("U",filectime($srcDir . '/' . $file)) >= time() - 3600) {
```

this is untested